# Parsing complex Json retrieved from API

Tags: json, pandas, api, python-requests

I'm trying to follow a tutorial on parsing complex JSON data from an API. Unfortunately I'm running into trouble, I believe the issue may be linked to different structure of the API JSON data, but I'm not 100% sure. Here is the starting point of my code, which seems to work fine.

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
import json
import pprint
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

base_url="https://data.sec.gov/api/xbrl/companyfacts/CIK0001627475.json"
headers={'User-Agent': 'Microsoft Edge My Header data'}
first_response=requests.get(base_url,headers=headers)
response_list=first_response.json()
print(response_list)
```

Where I run into trouble is where I go to parse and create a PD DataFrame as follows;

```
data=[]
for respone in response_list:
    data.append({"cik":response.get('cik'),"entityName":response.get('entityName')}
base_df=pd.DataFrame(data)
base_df.head()
```

Even though I'm pretty sure I've folloewed the tutorial directly (with different API data) I get the following error;

```
File "<ipython-input-34-8206debe28ba>", line 4
    my_df=pd.DataFrame(data)
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I'd love to understand the error here and how to understand the types of requests I need to send to break such a complex JSON data set down and retrieve the relevant columns from the sub sections of FACTS, DEI, US-GAAP etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a `SyntaxError` because you forgot the ')' a the end of your previous line:

```
data.append({"cik":response.get('cik'),
             "entityName":response.get('entityName')})  # <- HERE ')'
```

But now, your code will raised an `AttributeError`. You don't need to iterate over `response_list` because in fact, it's not a list but a dictionary:

```
>>> type(response_list)
dict
```

Therefore, your code could be simply:

```
base_df = pd.DataFrame(response_list)
```

```
>>> base_df
             cik   entityName                                              facts
dei      1627475  UPWORK INC.  {'EntityCommonStockSharesOutstanding': {'label...
us-gaap  1627475  UPWORK INC.  {'AccountsPayableCurrent': {'label': 'Accounts...
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you very much. If I wanted to delve deeper into the JSON, to the DEI, US GAAP etc levels, would it be at that point I would need to iterate? Would I then need to specify which area to iterate or just use the original code above that you mention caused an attribute error on the CIK and EntityName?

Comment: Your data structure is really complex and very nested. I don't think you can extract in one pass only. You have really to know what you need before extract data. `pd.json_normalize` can help you.

Comment: If you post another question about your structure, don't hesitate to post a comment here to notify me. I'll try to answer. (and ty)

Comment: Thanks, I've posted a new question showing the attribute error, I'd like to understand how to navigate the various levels of JSON structure.